# Force mouse click on popup window

Tags: javascript

I have a simple project but i'm newbie in javascript,
what I need is to force mouse to click on a dialog when the user leaves the page

[image: Confirm dialog on leaving page]

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the event, "onbeforeunload" attached has the window:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on "unload" event ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/K5FzG/1/

On the unload call, you just need to call

```
confirm('Are you sure ?');
```

or like said in comment "onbeforeunload" if you want to use objects in page

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

Comment: I think is better to use "onbeforeunload" to keep all objects in the document alive